# Replacing images via CSS

Tags: html, css

Im working on making a stream overlay by using custom CSS over the discord streamkit. I you are unfamiliar it will generate a transparent layover of the people talking in your discord channels of their avatars. Im trying to change this via CSS in OBS and ive run into a snag

The html is pretty simple

```
<ul class="voice-states" data-reactid=".0.0.0"><li class="voice-state" data reactid=".0.0.0.$133103869378035712/=1$133103869378035712">
<img class="avatar" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/133103869378035712/6819c76e3ea0cbc2c9cb22566994831f.jpg" data-reactid=".0.0.0.$133103869378035712/=1$133103869378035712.$=10">
```

So to replace the image I used

```
.voice-state  img
{
content: url("https://i.imgur.com/b1jD5Yd.jpg");
}
```

to replace the picture but the problem when with multiple voice states are being used when more than one person is in the channel and is differentiated by the `data-reactid` attr because right now it replaces all the avatars with that image and im trying to figure out a way to replace avatars individually from the reactid attr.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to style the images by the data-attributes then, if you know the IDs and they don't change. To  get the image to show up on top of the avatar, set a z-index that is higher than the avatar image.

```
[data-reactid="ID001"],
[data-reactid="ID002"] {
 background-image: url("image.jpg");
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1; 
}
```

Comment: So I have the IDs they are set on their profiles. There are four of them I just need to figure out how to set the image according to an ID because it looks like right now 

```<class="voice-state" data reactid="ID001> 
   <img class="avatar" src="image1.jpg" data reactid="ID001">
``<class="voice-state" data reactid="ID002> 
   <img class="avatar" src="image2.jpg" data reactid="ID002">```


Or my question is how would I map over each ID once I know the IDs

Comment: @ohlupo please update your answer with the css you added in your comment in order to get credit for answering the question. :)

Comment: Thanks you helped me answer my question by trying out something similar
```</code>
[data-reactid="ID001"]
{
content: 
url("image001.jpg")
}

[data-reactid="ID002"]
{
content: 
url("image002.jpg")
};
```